# Using Database with Phonegap App

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova, mobile

I am trying to create an easy application that shows the data from database. User enters the search key and will get the result but i don't know which database i need to use and where it will be located. I got lots of datas so i think that's not gonna be a local database. If i use SQLite,MSsql or MySql how can i get the datas ? Do i have to write a webservice that connects the database or can i do this in Phonegap html and javascript ?

I just wanna create a cross platform app so that's why i choose Phonegap but as i said really confuse what database i need to use and where it will located. Thanks!

Comment: Have alook at this plugin: https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

Comment: Thanks man i'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not preferred to use javascript to fetch data from database due to many security issues.
You can use a server side scripting language like php to create a web service to access the data from the database server.
The data flow will be like, catch the keyword from the user > post the keyword to the web service via ajax or http > fetch the data from the database server using the keyword and then return it to the user in a json format.

Comment: Thank you! I clearly understand what i really need to do :)